# Unique ID SQL Buddy

Tags: php, sql, sqlbuddy

What is the best way to create a unique id column for table records in SQL Buddy? I am new to all of this so excuse the ignorance. Is there some sort of auto number generator or something? I am assuming that the php script will check the table and insert the next number or something. Again, I am learning right now after using Caspio for a while. Sorry if this question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sqlbuddy, select the checkbox "auto increment." After that when you insert records into the table, that field will automatically increment to the next number.

You're also likely going to want to make the field the primary key. To do that, select the "primary" value from the key dropdown. This will index that field as a unique value.

Also, just to be clear - you'll want to make sure that field is an Integer. Select int in the type dropdown.